# How to batch create users in Parse via REST api

Tags: javascript, python, rest, parse-platform

I have roughly 1.5 million users I need to import into my parse _User table (we are migrating from our old sql db to Parse).

I've tried using a Background Job, but it is slow and gets killed every 15 minutes.  As a result, we have only import ~300K users in 4 days.

So I decided to go the REST api route...and tried the PythonPy lib.  It works, except for being able to do batch creation of users.  From digging more into this, it seems that the REST api forces you to do a User.signup() call.

This of course makes the whole thing be serialized.

Is there anyway to do batch user creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch creating / signing up User objects is not supported in Parse. It is mentioned in this question:
https://parse.com/questions/what-user-operations-are-supported-in-batch

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately Parse has a great service that they go out of their way to continuously add barriers to use.  Thanks anyways :)